# Which setting of the ThemeRoller corredponds to the header of jqGrid?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid, themeroller, jquery-ui-theme

I built a custom jQuery UI Theme using ThemeRoller based of the UI Lightness theme. My jqGrid now looks like this

[image]

From my investigation, the header is using the css classes `ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr` and is using the background image: `images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png` from `jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.css`.

What setting do I have change in the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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) to change the Header color?

Comment: ThemeRoller can only generate themes for the widgets provided by jQuery UI. jqGrid not being part of jQuery UI, I'm afraid you will have to add `.ui-th-column` rules to your CSS files manually, at least for now (the upcoming grid widget might use the same classes as jqGrid and ThemeRoller will probably be updated accordingly upon release).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current jQuery.UI: 1.10.2 and the current jqGrid: 4.4.4, I was able to change the header by setting the Clickable: default state of the [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller)